# How to check jqgrid checkbox by option outside the grid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I have a jqgrid with a checkbox as a leading column. I need to be able to use an optiongroup outside of the grid to either **check All** or **uncheck All** or **check Some** of the rows

```
<input id="rblAll" type="radio" name="rblOptStatus" value="All"/>Check All
<input id="rblNone" type="radio" name="rblOptStatus" value="None"/>Uncheck All
<input id="rblSome" type="radio" name="rblOptStatus" value="Some"/>Check 60%
<input id="rblReset" type="radio" name="rblOptStatus" value="Reset"  checked="checked" />Reset
```

So my grid is a loadOnce: true and multiselect is false. The column model is

```
colModel: [
        { name: 'ab', index: 'ab', width: 50, sortable: true, search: false, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false }, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'True:False' } },
```

This is the code I was trying to use but the checkbox is not set.

```
$("input[name=rblOptStatus]").change(function () {
    var OptStatus = $("input[name=rblOptStatus]:checked").val()
    if (OptStatus == 'All') {
        var rows = jQuery("#grdOptionsGrid").getDataIDs();
        for (a = 0; a < rows.length; a++) {
            var q = jQuery("#grdOptionsGrid").jqGrid('getCell', rows[a], 'ab'); // displays true, for a checked record.
            if (q == 'False') {
                //MsgBox(q);
                //jQuery("#grdOptionsGrid").jqGrid('getCell', rows[a], 'ab').prop('checked', true);
                $(this).prop('checked', 'True')
            }
        }
```

So how should I be looping through the grid and then checking/unchecking the rows checkbox.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getGridRowById` to get DOM element of row (`<tr>`). The method `getCell` gets the *value* (the text) and you can't use `.prop('checked', true)` to check the checkbox. The fixed code could be like

```js
$("input[name=rblOptStatus]").change(function () {
    var status = $("input[name=rblOptStatus]:checked").val(),
        $grid = $("#grdOptionsGrid"),
        ids = $grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs"),
        setCheckboxes = function (maxIndex, value) {
            var i, $checkbox;
            for (i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
                $checkbox = $($grid.jqGrid('getGridRowById', ids[i]))
                        .children('td[aria-describedby="grdOptionsGrid_ab"]')
                        .find('input');
                if ($checkbox.is(":checked") !== value) {
                    $checkbox.prop('checked', value);
                }
            }
        };
    switch (status) {
        case 'All':
            setCheckboxes(ids.length, true);
            break;
        case 'None':
            setCheckboxes(ids.length, false);
            break;
        default: //Check 60%
            setCheckboxes(ids.length, false);
            setCheckboxes(ids.length*0.6, true);
    }
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ef6zp25g/

Comment: Oleg, I get the following error  jqGrid - No such method: getGridRowById. What version is this in?

Comment: @TomS: **Which version you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?** I used in my demo free jqGrid 4.13.0. Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting with the end 2014 after changing license agreement, making it commercial and renaming [the main fork](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) to Guriddo jqGrid JS. I provide free jqGrid under the same old MIT/GPLv2 license (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)).

Comment: @TomS: The method `getGridRowById` exists already in version 4.5.3 published in 2013. If you use more old version (some retro version) then you can use `$grid.jqGrid('getInd', rowid, true)` instead of `$grid.jqGrid('getGridRowById', ids[i])`, but I would you strictly recommend to upgrade to more recent version.

Comment: I am using jqGrid  4.4.0 - jQuery Grid and I get the error that this method does not exist.

Comment: @TomS: jqGrid 4.4.0 is published 4 year ago, which is very much for the web development. It included for example retro jQuery version 1.4.3 under which it's tested. It have a lot of compatibility problems with the current versions of web browsers and current versions of jQuery, jQuery UI, ... As I wrote you can use `getInd` instead of `getGridRowById`, but I strictly recommend you to upgrade jqGrid to free jqGrid 4.13.0 and to the recent version of jQuery and jQuery UI CSS or Bootsrtap CSS.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, based on your example using the Closed column as my Check 60%, how would I work the switch to only check those rows where Closed is checked?

Comment: @TomS: Which `datatype` you use? If you use `datatype: "local"` or `datatype: "json"` with `loadonce: true` then you can get the data by rowid using `getLocalRow: `$grid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', ids[i]).closed`. If you have no local data, then it's better to use `$grid.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'closed')` instead of `$grid.jqGrid('getRowData', ids[i]).closed`. Having the information you can modify the loop from my demo for additional criteria.